# How does a function caller use a header file to determine what to do with a compiled binary?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, compiler-theory

My understanding is that C++ (and C, I guess) header files are never compiled, and simply act as an explanation of the interface of the C++ file they describe.

So if my header file describes a hello() function, some program that includes the header will know about hello() and how to call it and what arguments to give it, etc.

However, after compilation (and before linking, I guess? I'm not sure), when the hello.c file is binary machine code, and hello.h is still C++, how does the compiler/linker know how to call a function in the binary blob based on the presence of its declaration in the header file?

I understand concepts such as symbol tables, abstract syntax trees, etc (i.e., I have taken a compiler class in the past), but this is a gap in my knowledge).

Comment: In C++ we use "declare" instead of describe. Translation unit is the term you should get familiar with, that will more or less answer your question.

Comment: "when the hello.c file is binary machine code, and hello.h is still C++" uhm no, it doesn't go like that. All the #include directives are replaced by the preprocessor by a textual copy-paste of  relevant file, so it's not correct to say that the code contained in the header is not compiled - it's just compiled inside the rest of the .c

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of hello() assumes a certain calling convention (where are the parameters on the stack, who cleans up the stack the caller or the callee, etc).

The compiler generates code with the correct calling convention.  It may use information from the header file to do this (e.g. the function is marked __stdcall in Windows program) or it may use it's default calling convention.  The compiler will also use the header file to make sure your are calling the routine with the right number and types of parameters.  Once the code is generated by the compiler the header file is not used again.

The linker is not concerned with calling convention it's primary responsibility is to patch together the binaries you've compiled by fixing up references among your modules and any libraries it calls.

Answer (score 0):

A C/C++ compilation unit (cpp file / c file) includes all the header files (as text) and the code.

The header file helps explain how to produce the call instruction

```
 push arg1
 push arg2
 call _some_function
```

If the compilation unit includes `_some_function` then this will be resolved at compile time.

Otherwise it becomes an *undefined symbol*.  If so, when the linker comes along, it looks through all the object files and libraries to resolve all the *undefined symbols*.

- So the header file helps code the assembly correctly.
- Object and library files provide implementations.

The library files are optional.  When a linker looks in a library file, it only gets added if it satisfies some symbol, otherwise it is not added to the binary.

Object files (ignoring optimization) will get added to the binary completely.

Comment: "If the compilation unit includes _some_function then this will be resolved at compile time."       It's resolved at link time, not compile time.

Answer (score -1):

Building a C++ program is a two-step process: compile and link. 
The header is for compilation of the module you are writing. The binary is for linking: it contains the compiled code for the method defined in the correspnding header. The header has to match what's already been compiled. At link time you will learn if your header has a method signature that matches what was compiled in the binary.

Comment: I'd sure like to know why someone thinks this should be down-voted.

Comment: I don't think the statement "At link time you will learn if your header has a method signature that matches what was compiled in the binary." is correct.  I should have commented.

Comment: It's completely correct. You should have stopped to think.

Comment: @JJF, as far as I know, Delmer is correct. I just did a quick search and I read over [a relevant article written by Alex Allain](http://www.cprogramming.com/compilingandlinking.html) (the author of *Jumping Into C++*). That article seems to support Delmer's statement.

Comment: @SpencerDoak Maybe we just have a terminology problem.  AFAIK no linker takes a header file as input so if the linker never reads the header I don't see how it's possible that the linker could complain that what's in the object file doesn't match what's in header.   The linker will complain if it finds a *symbol* in an object file for which it cannot find a definition for.  That symbol name in the case of a function call did come from a header or prototype but it was generated (name mangled) by the compiler.  The linker still knows nothing about the header file from my understanding.

Comment: The code gets compiled regardless of an existing implementation.  However the header file changes the compiler's choices by supplying argument types.  The name mangled function then creates a specific required target.  If the C++ file included an implementation, then this is bound. Otherwise an undefined symbol record is created.  In some senses the include file can change the function. (bool test( int ) vs int test(long) )